# Problem with developing Engines with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, predictionio

I like to use developing and debugging engines with IntelliJ IDEA, but I got an error. I used this link: https://predictionio.apache.org/resources/intellij/.
Please guide me.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.ParserUtil$.quote(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonMethods.scala:42)
at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonMethods.scala:42)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$class.render(JsonMethods.scala:42)
at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$.render(JsonMethods.scala:62)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.WorkflowUtils$$anonfun$getParamsFromJsonByFieldAndClass$2$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkflowUtils.scala:177)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.WorkflowUtils$$anonfun$getParamsFromJsonByFieldAndClass$2$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkflowUtils.scala:168)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.WorkflowUtils$$anonfun$getParamsFromJsonByFieldAndClass$2.apply(WorkflowUtils.scala:168)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.WorkflowUtils$$anonfun$getParamsFromJsonByFieldAndClass$2.apply(WorkflowUtils.scala:159)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.WorkflowUtils$.getParamsFromJsonByFieldAndClass(WorkflowUtils.scala:159)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine.jValueToEngineParams(Engine.scala:363)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:222)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
```

Comment: did you get any workaround?

Comment: i can't find any solution for it. :((

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fix it changing the scala version to 2.11.3 in build.sbt. 
The json library used by predictionio uses the scala's  version 2.11.3 .